# Override hibernate physical naming strategy | @Column not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy = 'Myclass'` in `application.yml.` Which works fine and converts field names to capitalized Db column name. But if want to not use it for a particular column name and provide a different name I'm unable to do it.

```
public class SomeModel{
...
@Column(name="lolwa")
String laughter
...
}
```

My naming strategy converts the fieldName to `LAUGHTER`, but I want it to be `lolwa` . How can I override that

Comment: When you're querying `SomeModel`, is the sql containing `LAUGHTER`?

Comment: No LAUGHTER is the DB column name, and my naming Strategy converts field names to CAPS before mapping. So it does right thing, but I want to disable that for a particular column using @Column

Comment: I'm  sorry, I don't fully understand. You're problem is that in this example field name is converted to `LAUGHTER` although `@Column` specifies otherwise?

Comment: Yes .. @column should override `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` given in application.yml. but it doesn't